# JavaScript. How to change some data in object via function for array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

Maybe somebody knows how to change some data in an object via a function for an array?

For example, I have an object:

```
var nodes = [
  { topic: "Games",    topicscore: 100},
  { topic: "Fun",      topicscore: 550},
  { topic: "New York", topicscore: 7799},
  { topic: "Hillary",  topicscore: 745},
  { topic: "Politics", topicscore: 512},
  { topic: "Trump",    topicscore: 71}
];
```

And I have a function:

```
var filterScoreValues = function(array_input){
  var a_out = [];
  array_input.forEach(function(x){
    a_out.push(Math.ceil(x / Math.max.apply(null,array_input) * 10) + 5)
  });
  return a_out;
};
```

How I can apply this algorithm to `topicscore` of my object?

I wrote this, but I want a "pretty" variant, maybe via lodash or similar:

```
function filterScoreValues(input){
  var array = input.map(function (i) {
    return i.topicscore;
  });

  array.forEach(function(x, index){
    input[index]['topicscore'] = Math.ceil(x / Math.max.apply(null, array) * 10) + 5;
  });

  return input;
 };
```

I often used loops on my variant.. :(

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? You only need to do `Math.max.apply(null,array)` once, not on every loop.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide the expected output from filterScoreValues method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to change some data in an object via a function

Use the following optimized approach(*without a function. It may be wrapped into function if there would be a need to call such function multiple times*):

```js
var nodes = [
  { topic: "Games",    topicscore: 100},
  { topic: "Fun",      topicscore: 550},
  { topic: "New York", topicscore: 7799},
  { topic: "Hillary",  topicscore: 745},
  { topic: "Politics", topicscore: 512},
  { topic: "Trump",    topicscore: 71}
];

// taking max 'topicscore' at once
var max_score = Math.max.apply(null, nodes.map(function (o) {
    return o.topicscore;    
}));
// processing each 'topicscore' item in place(without creating temporary arrays)
nodes.forEach(function (o) {
    o.topicscore = Math.ceil(o.topicscore / max_score * 10) + 5;
});

console.log(nodes);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array#map` to extract the `topicscore` to an array. Calculate the `max` once using the `topicscores` array. Then `Array#map` the `topicscores` array into a normalized array using `max`.

```js
var nodes = [
  { topic: "Games",    topicscore: 100},
  { topic: "Fun",      topicscore: 550},
  { topic: "New York", topicscore: 7799},
  { topic: "Hillary",  topicscore: 745},
  { topic: "Politics", topicscore: 512},
  { topic: "Trump",    topicscore: 71}
];

function filterScoreValues(input){
  var topicscores = input.map(function (i) { return i.topicscore; }); // extract the topicscores to array
  
  var max = Math.max.apply(null, topicscores); // calc the max
  
  return topicscores.map(function (score) { // map normalize and return the new array
    return Math.ceil(score / max * 10) + 5;
  });
};

var result = filterScoreValues(nodes);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use javascript:

```
filterScoreValues(nodes.map(node => node.topicscore));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is:

```
var nodes = [
  { topic: "Games",    topicscore: 100},
  { topic: "Fun",      topicscore: 550},
  { topic: "New York", topicscore: 7799},
  { topic: "Hillary",  topicscore: 745},
  { topic: "Politics", topicscore: 512},
  { topic: "Trump",    topicscore: 71}
];
function filterScoreValues(input){
  var array = input.map(function (i) {
    return i.topicscore;
  });

  array.forEach(function(x, index){
    input[index].topicscore = Math.ceil(x / Math.max.apply(null, array) * 10) + 5;
  });

  return input;
 };
console.log(filterScoreValues(nodes));
```